# works in page inspector but not in debug

Tags: jquery-plugins, fullcalendar, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, page-inspector

is there any reason for something to work in page inspector and not in real debug mode?
In particular I'm using fullcalendar.min.js (JQuery plugin) in some tab content and I see it very well in page inspector but when debug the calander is not shown..

in header:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./../../Content/fullcalendar.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="./../../Scripts/js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

in body:

```
 <section class="tab events-tab">
    <section class="events-tab-inner">
    <div id="calendar"></div>
    </section>
    </section>
```

in console of the web page loading I have the below errors (I'm not sure they are directly related to my calendar thing):

```
GET http://localhost:3516/SITE/css/images/star-off.png 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:2
Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. all.js:56
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.min.js:3
FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init(). all.js:56
GET http://localhost:3516/SITE/css/images/star-off.png 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:2
```

Comment: Do you see an error messages in the console when debugging?

Comment: in "Output" view, when reaching the page I see only : 'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130317815444513334): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\a6925d18\7d2f13f6\App_Web_xrckkjml.dll'.

Comment: I'm newbie in this web thing - is there like another way to debug web page? something with chrome and so to see if the plugin is correctly loaded and all?

Comment: If you run from VS, it should open a browser (I think. Don't hold me to that). Depending on your browser, most of them come with debugging consoles. When the site opens, select <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the Developer Tools Window. There should be a tab somewhere on that panel to view the browser console.

Comment: Thanks appreciate that, really cool. I'll attach it to question..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your console output that you've included above, it seems that there are a few errors. Not sure why they would work in page inspector and not debug though. It seems like it should be breaking everywhere. Let's approach each error one by one:

**1. Invalid Image Paths**

It appears that you may be using ***jQuery UI*** for some features within your code. The jQuery UI suite contains images located in the `/images` directory when you download the `.zip` file that the CSS references as `background-images`. These images are expected to be nested on directory in from the location of the CSS file. For example,

```
[CSS Directory]
    -> jquery-ui.min.css
    [images]
        -> star-off.png
        -> ...
        -> etc.
```

The only way to change this structure is to modify the relative urls within the minified jQuery UI CSS file.

**2. Facebook JavaScript SDK error**

I have never personally used the Facebook JavaScript SDK. However, that is what it appears you are using. From the error it sounds like you never initialize the Facebook object via `FB.init()` before you call `FB.getLoginStatus()`. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* Locate your FB.getLoginStatus() call and place FB.init() before it */
    FB.init();
    FB.getLoginStatus();
</script>
```

Other than that, you may need to refer to their documentation for how to properly initialize the `FB` object for use.

Hope this helps. Good luck and happy coding! :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll address the issues above and hopefully my calendar will pop up, will update soon..